# TeamCity. Artifacts during the construction of the project on the first agent were transferred to the second agent

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have a build server and two build agents. On one agent, I have a build project. The second agent is the agent that is configured to deploy the application to the server. I need artifacts to be transferred to the second agent during the construction of the project on the first agent. Tell me roughly where these configurations are?

Comment: If you want two build configurations where artifacts produced by one is made available to the other you should look into "Dependencies". You can set up "Snapshot dependencies", which means build configurations will run against the same commit/changeset, and "Artifact dependencies" which allow you to grab files from one build configuration's artifacts and make them available for another build configuration.

Comment: Also, please edit the question so it makes sense. You usually don't have a build "project" on *1* build agent, you configure the project and build configuration on the server and the server will distribute builds across the available (and possible) build agents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original question is a little bit confusing -- it would be nice if you could edit it and improve, so it would be more clear what you want.
I don't understand the phrase

> The second agent is deployed.

Is your application deployed on the agent itself or the agent deployed on the Teamcity?

Nevertheless, what you can do is configure [artifact dependency](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Artifact+Dependencies): which would let you to transfer artifacts from one build to another (without filtering by agents).